# How could I call hundreds in python?

Tags: python, split, numbers, digits

When I split certain numbers into "ones" and "tens" in python, like that (98) we code >>>

```
num = 98
ones = num % 10 
tens = num // 10 
print(ones) = 8 
print(tens) = 9
```

So, if I have 3 digits number like 321 (based on the code have shown previously) the ones will be 1, tens = 32 . and I need python to execute 3 and 2 separately !!

Comment: Do you mean `hundreds = num // 100`? That should be apparent from what you have already.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Do you understand *why* `num % 10` yields 8 and `num // 10` yields 9?

Comment: Hint: look at `321 % 1` and `321 % 10`, and see if you can detect a pattern. Do the same for `321 // 1` and `321 // 10`.

Comment: @Axe319 Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Classic. we can do your comp sci homework :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
tens, ones = divmod(98, 10)
tens
# 9
ones
# 8
```

Second, you could write a generic function to get all digits regardless of magnitude:

```
def digs(n):
    while n:
        n, dig = divmod(n, 10)
        yield dig

ones, tens, hundreds, *_ = digs(321)
```

It will always produce all digits starting with ones:

```
[*digs(12345)]
# [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Of course, the simplest is just string conversion:

```
[*map(int, str(12345))]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic Python code to split the digits (ones, tens, hundreds, and so on)

```
num = int(input())

count = 0
while (num != 0):
    mod = num % 10
    div = num // 10
    count = count + 1

    print ("The number in position", count, " is ", mod)
    num = div
```

This code works by repeated division.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function doing the modulo operations, put those in a list, make the division by then and repeat until the end, reverse the list:

```
def split_number(number):
    result = []
    while number != 0:
        result.append(number % 10)
        number = number // 10
    result.reverse()
    return result
```

```
split_number(12345)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

like this :

```
321 / 100
3.21
>>> int(3.21)
3
```

But you have already made a better thing for 10 why you don't make it for 100?

Comment: There's no need to get into floating-point arithmetic here.

Comment: Yes ! but its a possibility

Comment: It's an unnecessary digression. The OP already knows about integer division, which is all that's needed to solve the problem. The only change necessary is the divisor used.